# Populate Timestamps of last modfied Filelist (A) in Column B

Tags: excel, timestamp, vba

Column A contains the filename without extension, I would like Column B to show the last modified Time and Date.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Path As String
Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E").Range("B14")
Range("B4").Value = FileDateTime(Path & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projekterfassung_Monitoring").Range("A4") & ".xlsx")
Range("B5").Value = FileDateTime(Path & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projekterfassung_Monitoring").Range("A5") & ".xlsx")
Range("B6").Value = FileDateTime(Path & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projekterfassung_Monitoring").Range("A6") & ".xlsx")
Range("B7").Value = FileDateTime(Path & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projekterfassung_Monitoring").Range("A7") & ".xlsx")
(...)
End Sub
```

How can I automate this, so that I don't have to write a line in code for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to implement a basic loop

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim i As Long
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E").Range("B14")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projekterfassung_Monitoring")
        For i = 4 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("B" & i).Value = FileDateTime(Path & .Range("A" & i) & ".xlsx")
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```